# How to make pip install python 2.x modules in python 3.x

Tags: python, pip

I would like to install the mailer library with pip, but it imports the module Queue, which has been renamed in python 3 to queue, how can I download it using pip?

Comment: that will almost definitely not work, if there is no package for python3 then you are out of luck

Comment: can you link to the package you are talking about?

Comment: Reading from the comments in the version history of mailer [here](https://bitbucket.org/ginstrom/mailer/src/ff2e4fa9db0854aa3f1adbf9454ff25e4ea8560d?at=default) it seems like it should be installable using python3. You should download the sources from bitbucket and run `python3 setup.py install`. If they did it properly the setup should be able to fix the code using `2to3`.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: **You cannot!**
Why would you even consider such thing?

This why so many project still use Python 2.7 and not 3.4, because so many modules are not ported yet.
However, more and more are, especially the famous ones.

The only thing you can do, is to find an equivalent / replacement module doing the same thing.

Update:

For creating queues, you could leverage the **Deque** (collections.deque) or find some implementations of queues using deque.

Comment: I'm not the one who voted down your answer, but I need this module, that's why I want to install it

Comment: @whiletrue For open-source packages, the other option is to contribute. If you feel that you're capable, do the community a service and port it over.

Comment: Yes, fork the project, and try to find what must be rewritten to make it 3.X compatible. Sometimes, it is not a big work. Then the community would help you to finalise it, even its creator would appreciate.